# How to Execute Python Code Within a Class By Importing It Specifically

Tags: python, python-import

How can I import a specific class and execute the code within by importing it?

Let's say that I have `x.py`:

```py
class classY:
    print('Executed class Y!')

class classZ:
    print('Executed class Z!')
```

I want the statement `print('Executed function Y!')` to execute when I import ONLY that module from another file.

For example, when I execute the command `from x import classY`, I would want the output in the console to be:

```py
>>>from x import classY
Executed class Y!
>>>
```

Currently, executing the same command with the same conditions results in both strings being printed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Anything that should be executed selectively must be in a function, which you can choose to call or not. All the top-level code is executed when you import, there's no way to be selective about it.

Comment: `from x import classY` just filters the *names* that are imported, it doesn't specify which code is executed.

Comment: Thank you @barmar! I'll take that into consideration when building future projects.

Comment: to get what you want, you could just split it into multiple files, then you can import just the ones you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially do it using module level `__getattr__` (see [PEP-562](https://peps.python.org/pep-0562/)). It would require either renaming your classes or placing them inside a namespace or a separate module to ensure `__getattr__` is called.

**x.py**

```py
class Namespace:

    class A:
        ...


    class B:
        ...


def __getattr__(name):
    cls = getattr(Namespace, name)
    if cls is not None:
        print(f"Imported class {cls.__name__}")
        return cls
    raise AttributeError(f"{name} invalid")
```

```py
>>> from x import A
Imported class A
```

Technically all the code within a class is executed *when it's defined*, but you can potentially put code inside functions and have it executed as part of the `getattr` function. Alternatively, you could save the class definitions as strings, and use `exec` to evaluate the strings in the `getattr` function.

```py
class_C = """
class C:
    print("Creating class C")
"""


def __getattr__(name):
    CLASS_DEFS = {"C": class_C}

    if name in CLASS_DEFS:
        exec(CLASS_DEFS[name], globals())
        return globals()[name]
    
    raise AttributeError(f"{name} invalid")
```

```py
>>> from x import C
Creating class C
```

Comment: Thank you @Brendan Abel! I will mark your answer as correct, although barmar gave a solution that works better for me.